# print string to terminal over and over again without flickering in python

Tags: python

I wrote a little python3 script, that runs another program with Popen and processes its output to create a little dashboard for it. The script generates a long string with information about the other program, clears the terminal and prints it. Everytime the screen refreshes, the whole terminal flickers.

here are the important parts of my script:

```
def screen_clear():
    if os.name == 'posix':
        os.system('clear')
    else:
        os.system('cls')

def display(lines):
    # lines as a list of, well, lines i guess
    s=''
    for line in lines:
        s=s + '\n' + str(line)
    screen_clear()
    print(s)
```

I bet theres a more elegant way without flickering to this, right?
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You're attempting to use a tool for something it's not intended for, and getting undesirable side-effects as a result.  You should _strongly_ reconsider your approach.

Comment: Stop clearing the screen.  If you want to clear everything, write the appropriate whitespace over the old text.

Comment: How do I write whitespace over it, if there are multiple lines? Do you maybe have an example somewhere? @WilliamPursell

Comment: @g.d.d.c Yes, I know... This is just a quick and dirty side project, that I wanted to make a little nicer.

Comment: @RockNLol You need to know who wide the terminal is and write the correct number of spaces.  Accurately determining that can be difficult, which is why libraries like curses exist.

Comment: Although it is often adequate to simply look at `os.environ['COLUMNS']`

Answer (score 1):

the only solution to try out I can think of would be using `print(s, end='\r')` instead of clearing the screen first and printing again. The \r marker tells the console to override the last line.

In the end I'm sorry to say that consoles are simply not made for using them as a dashboard with permanently changing values. If the aforementioned solution doesn't work, maybe try implementing your dashboard in another way, python offers lots of solutions for that.

Comment: Carriage returns (your `\r`) only affect a single _line_.  They'll do nothing to help with redrawing multiple lines.